# SharedFlow.last() never returns

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-sharedflow

I have a sharedFlow with a replay value of one. But when I am trying to access the last emitted value, the call never returns (while `first()` does).

Below is my code:

```
val game = GameSettingsRepository.gameIdFlow.flatMapLatest { gameId ->
    gameId?.let { gameDataSource.getGame(it) }
        ?: flowOf()
}.shareIn(ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycleScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, 1)
```

where `getGame()` is a callbackFlow:

```
override fun getGame(gameId: String): Flow<Game> = callbackFlow {
    val listener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            snapshot.getValue(GameFirebase::class.java)?.let { gameFirebase ->
                    trySend(gameFirebase.toData())
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    }
    db.child(gameId).addValueEventListener(listener)
    awaitClose { db.child(gameId).removeEventListener(listener) }
}
```

and so this: `val myGame = game.last()` never returns anything while `val myGame = game.first()`does.

Why and How?

Answer (score 8):

A SharedFlow is infinite. It stays open forever awaiting possible future emissions. Therefore, it has no last element.

The `last()` function works by collecting an entire Flow and then returning the last result. Since `collect()` never returns when called on a SharedFlow, `last()` can never return either. It will suspend forever.